# Exception in Tkinter callback + usb.core.USBError: [Errno 13] Access denied (insufficient permissions)

Tags: python, tkinter

I have written this python code to generate otp for the various systems. Im using a Epson   thermal printer to get the otp in hard copy. The error im facing is as follows. The otp is printed on the screen but not on my printer. It just prints 2 or 3 otps and then throws the following error. I have gone through very sources but im not finding the root of the error. I guess it is something related to threading as the same print function is printing properly in other python file. Do help me regarding this.

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\ADMIN\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\tkinter_*init*_.py", line 1892, in **call**
return self.func(*args)
File "C:\Users\ADMIN\PycharmProjects\ticketing\venv\lib\site-packages\customtkinter\widgets\ctk_button.py", line 390, in clicked
self.function()
File "C:\Users\ADMIN\PycharmProjects\ticketing\ADMIN\admin.py", line 133, in 
command=lambda: Animalsonfloor_fuction())
File "C:\Users\ADMIN\PycharmProjects\ticketing\ADMIN\admin.py", line 73, in Animalsonfloor_fuction
remove_line('animals_on_floor.txt')
File "C:\Users\ADMIN\PycharmProjects\ticketing\ADMIN\admin.py", line 40, in remove_line
print_function(data[0])
File "C:\Users\ADMIN\PycharmProjects\ticketing\ADMIN\admin.py", line 27, in print_function
p = Usb(0x04B8, 0x0E27, 0, 0x81, 0x02)
File "C:\Users\ADMIN\PycharmProjects\ticketing\venv\lib\site-packages\escpos\printer.py", line 52, in **init**
self.open(usb_args)
File "C:\Users\ADMIN\PycharmProjects\ticketing\venv\lib\site-packages\escpos\printer.py", line 74, in open
check_driver = self.device.is_kernel_driver_active(0)
File "C:\Users\ADMIN\PycharmProjects\ticketing\venv\lib\site-packages\usb\core.py", line 1107, in is_kernel_driver_active
self._ctx.managed_open()
File "C:\Users\ADMIN\PycharmProjects\ticketing\venv\lib\site-packages\usb\core.py", line 113, in wrapper
return f(self, *args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Users\ADMIN\PycharmProjects\ticketing\venv\lib\site-packages\usb\core.py", line 131, in managed_open
self.handle = self.backend.open_device(self.dev)
File "C:\Users\ADMIN\PycharmProjects\ticketing\venv\lib\site-packages\usb\backend\libusb1.py", line 804, in open_device
return _DeviceHandle(dev)
File "C:\Users\ADMIN\PycharmProjects\ticketing\venv\lib\site-packages\usb\backend\libusb1.py", line 652, in **init**
_check(_lib.libusb_open(self.devid, byref(self.handle)))
File "C:\Users\ADMIN\PycharmProjects\ticketing\venv\lib\site-packages\usb\backend\libusb1.py", line 604, in _check
raise USBError(_strerror(ret), ret, _libusb_errno[ret])
usb.core.USBError: [Errno 13] Access denied (insufficient permissions)

```
<code>


 #header files customtkinter installation pip3 install customtkinter

import tkinter
import customtkinter
from tkinter import simpledialog
from tkinter import messagebox
from PIL import Image, ImageTk

from escpos.printer import Usb
import usb.core
import usb.util
import usb.backend.libusb1

import threading
from threading import Thread


# this is the main function
customtkinter.set_appearance_mode("System")  # Modes: system (default), light, dark
customtkinter.set_default_color_theme("blue")  # Themes: blue (default), dark-blue, green

app = customtkinter.CTk()  # create CTk window like you do with the Tk window


# this function is to print the generated password.
def print_function(password):
    p = Usb(0x04B8, 0x0E27, 0, 0x81, 0x02)
    p.text('mdm \n\n\n\n'  "OTP FOR SYSTEM IS \n\n\n " 
+ password)
    p.cut()
print(password)




# this function is to remove the generated password.
def remove_line(fileName):
    with open(fileName, 'r') as fin:
        data = fin.read().splitlines(True)
        messagebox.showinfo("Password", 'Password is:- ' + data[0])
        print_function(data[0])
    with open(fileName, 'w') as fout:
        fout.writelines(data[1:])



# this function is to generate password for aerospace
def aerospace_function():
    remove_line('aerospace.txt')


# this function is to generate password for parachute function.
def parachute_function():
    remove_line('parachute.txt')


# this function is for bikeVr
def bikeVr_function():
    remove_line('motorbike.txt')


# this function is to generate password for mind-game.
def Mindgame_function():
    remove_line('mind_game.txt')


# this function is to generate password for cricket_Vr.
def CricketVR_function():
    remove_line('cricket_vr.txt')


# this function is to generate password for animals on floor
def Animalsonfloor_fuction():
    remove_line('animals_on_floor.txt')


# this functon is to generate password for  human anatomy
def HumanAnatomy_function():
    remove_line('human_anatomy.txt')


#this is for closing the program it asks the user to enter the password until the admin enters 
#the correct password the program cannot be stopped
def close_win():
    password_value = simpledialog.askstring("Close", "Enter the closing password:", 
    parent=app, show="*")
    if password_value == "12345":
        app.destroy()
    else:
        messagebox.showerror("Error", "Wrong password")

# this is the first windows of the program it will be open until the user enters the 
  #correct password
def start_game():
    password_value = simpledialog.askstring("Close", "Enter the Password:", parent=app, 
    show="*")
    if password_value == "12345":
        return True
    else:
        messagebox.showerror("Error", "Wrong password")
        return False

def disable_event():
    pass


#unless the user press the close button or enter the correcct password the program will run
while True:
    if start_game():
        break

image = Image.open("datalogo.png")
bg_image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image)
image_label = tkinter.Label(master=app, image=bg_image)
image_label.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.5, anchor=tkinter.CENTER)


# below labels and buttons are made using Custom tkinter.
label_1 = customtkinter.CTkLabel(master=app, text="SELECT THE APP", text_color="white")
label_1.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.1, anchor=tkinter.CENTER)

aerospace_button = customtkinter.CTkButton(master=app, text="Aerospace VR", command=lambda: 
aerospace_function())
aerospace_button.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.2, anchor=tkinter.CENTER)

parachute_button = customtkinter.CTkButton(master=app, text="Parachute VR", command=lambda: 
parachute_function())
parachute_button.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.3, anchor=tkinter.CENTER)

bikeVr_button = customtkinter.CTkButton(master=app, text="Bike VR", command=lambda: 
bikeVr_function())
bikeVr_button.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.4, anchor=tkinter.CENTER)

mindgame_button = customtkinter.CTkButton(master=app, text="Mind Game", command=lambda: 
Mindgame_function())
mindgame_button.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.5, anchor=tkinter.CENTER)

cricketvr_button = customtkinter.CTkButton(master=app, text="Cricket VR", command=lambda: 
CricketVR_function())
cricketvr_button.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.6, anchor=tkinter.CENTER)

animalsonfloor_button = customtkinter.CTkButton(master=app, text="Animals on Floor",
                                            command=lambda: Animalsonfloor_fuction())
animalsonfloor_button.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.7, anchor=tkinter.CENTER)


humananatomy_button = customtkinter.CTkButton(master=app, text="Human Anatomy", 
command=lambda: HumanAnatomy_function())
humananatomy_button.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.8, anchor=tkinter.CENTER)


close_button = customtkinter.CTkButton(master=app, text="Close", command=close_win)
close_button.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.9, anchor=tkinter.CENTER)


# disabling the close,minimize and maximize window.
app.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", disable_event)
app.attributes('-fullscreen', True)
app.mainloop()

</code>
```

Comment: I am not familiar with the `escpos` module you used in your code. But from the error msg, it appears an error occurred at `p = Usb(0x04B8, 0x0E27, 0, 0x81, 0x02)` in `print_function`

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).